# choosing random_State parameter in TSNE (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have two questions, I am trying to plot my data with [`bh_sne`](https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne) library, however as the nature of this algorithm is based on random number in each run I have a different result. I would like to get the same result at each run. it seems that `random_state` is helpful.
But I do not know what exactly does it mean, by choosing different integer number for `random_state`.

For example what is the different between `random_state=0` and `random_state=1` or `random_state=42` .. and `random_state=None`

Second, when I applied this parameter in my function and by giving any values except None I got the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

I do not have any files that named as random in my pycharm.

this is my code:

```
data = bh_sne(X, random_state =1 )
```

`X` contains my features values.

Comment: What library? I added a link, but not sure it is the correct link. Are you using [this one](https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne)?

Comment: from tsne import bh_sne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lib uses numpy's random-module, more specific: [this part](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState).

Just use it like that:

```
import numpy as np

bh_sne(X, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))  # init with integer 0
```

This can be seen with a simple source-search for random (see picture below), which also shows some unit-test!

An integer (0 above) is just some source of entropy, which results in *some* state of the internal random-number generator. Without analyzing the PRNG there are no guarantees how a seed-number of 0 behaves compared to 1 or 40. It does not need to be different (but often is)!

There is only one guarantee: determinism! Grabbing random-numbers from a PRNG initialized with number `seed=my_integer`, returns the same path / the same numbers each time this is done with this exact seed (first x numbers are equal each time; x arbitrary).

But the [intro-page](https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne#python-tsne) probably gives a more important notice (which was my first question when i saw what lib you are using while working in python):

**Note: Scikit-learn v0.17 includes TSNE algorithms and you should probably be using them instead of this.**

[image]